# .htaccess RewriteRule is not working on my localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am fairly new to php and RewriteRules, I tried to make localhost/webapp/sign_up.php point to localhost/webapp/sign_up. This is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sign_up/?$ sign_up.php
```

but when I go to localhost/webapp/sign_up it says:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /webapp/sign_up was not found on this server.
```

I am using apache2 (Ubuntu) by the way and I am sure rewrite_mod is enabled.

In case it helps, my .htaccess is under var/www/html/webapp

Comment: why are you sure rewrite_mod is enabled? have you restarted apache?

Comment: Yeah I did. When I run the command a2enmode rewrite on the terminal it says "Module rewrite already enabled". and Yeah, I started apache2 but it's still not working. It's the same 404 Not Found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /webapp/
RewriteRule ^([a-z_]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

And make sure the mod_rewrite module is enabled by running these commands

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And if all else fails please try setting a [virualhost](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) and after read this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04) about setting up mod_rewrite

Comment: It's the same. I think the problem isn't in the rewrite rule itself. Maybe the server is not reading it or something.

Comment: @Alaa, try reloading using `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Done but it is still the same damn error. I tried to put the .htaccess under www/html/ but it's the same.

Comment: @Alaa, try my new edited answer and also make sure you put the webapp folder under `/var/www/html/` and also the `.htaccess` should be directly under `/var/www/html/webapp/` and make sure the permissions under that folder are properly set

Comment: I did everything but unfortunately, the error won't go away ... I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Could you show a sample of your error log after accessing your the same web page by going to the terminal and running the following command `less error.log | tail` under `/var/log/apache2`

Comment: Here it is: **[Sat Aug 12 17:30:55.451919 2017] [negotiation:error] [pid 21153] [client 127.0.0.1:53094] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/html/webapp/sign_up (None could be negotiated)., referer: http://localhost/webapp/**

Comment: Add `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` to your `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf` and restart apache. Make sure you add it before the closing `</IfModule>` and also make sure you do it under sudo privileges

Comment: It worked!!!!!!!! Thaaaaaank you so much!!!!! Can you please tell me what was wrong so I learn something new? :D

Comment: You are welcome and you can read more about that issue [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/372733/apache-file-negotiation-failed) but since you are just getting started with php, may i suggest you first master php first before moving on to the advanced apache configuration stuff because trust me it's alot. Please it would help if you upvote my answer too. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help more:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It allows you to put the .php away everywhere

Comment: Still the same problem. 404 Not Found. :(

Comment: But localhost/webapp/sign_up.php have no 404?

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sign_up/sign_up.php/$1 [L]